# How to check that all random array elements are different

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I'm trying to pass random integers (between 0 and 11) to the Numbers[] array, but i have to make sure that all 10 of its elements are different. I've tried to pass the numbers first in the array, and then check if there are any numbers that are equal but its not working this way. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Numbers[10];
    srand( time(NULL) );

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        Numbers[i] = rand() % 12;         // First, the integers are passed 
        to the array (They must be between 0 and 11)
        cout << Numbers[i] << endl;        // and printed to the screen
    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    for (int u = 0; u < 10; u++)
    {
        if(Numbers[u] == Numbers[u - 1])      // If there are two equal 
numbers 
     {
       switch (Numbers[u])     // One of them is incremented (But that 
    causes problems as well because it can lead to another pair of equals)
       {
       case 11:     // In case one of them is 11
        Numbers[u]--;
        break;

       default:
        Numbers[u]++;
        break;

       }
     }
     cout << Numbers[u] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Halp!

Comment: Just initialize array sequencially and use `std::shuffle` and you do not need to validate.

Comment: 1) "_but its not working this way_" Not working.. How? 2) "_// If there are two equal numbers_" That's **not** what that line checks.. It checks if two **neighboring** elements are equal. 3) Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: "but i have to make sure that all 10 of its elements are different" - Then you could simply add numbers to a `std::set` until it contains 10 elements, then you'll have 10 unique elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `std::vector`, `std::iota` and `std::shuffle`:

```
std::vector<int> v( 12 );
std::iota( v.begin(), v.end(), 0 ); // initialize with values 0..11
std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});  // make em random
v.resize( 10 ); // remove extra elements
```

and you do not need to validate that all elements are unique

Comment: thanks for the answer, but is there a way to do this without implementing vectors?

Comment: Yes create array of size 12 and use first 10 elements from it as your numbers

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question that you are trying to read random numbers till all 10 numbers are different. Have a look on code below:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <bitset>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {

        int Numbers[10] ;
        srand(time(NULL));

        //Keep flag with all the bits '0' initially
        bitset<12> flags;
        flags.reset();

        // keep taking input till all bits are not '1'
        int i = 0;
        do
        {
            int in_num = rand() % 12;
            // check if the bit at position "in_num" is 0
            if (!flags[in_num])
            {
                Numbers[i++] = in_num;
                flags.set(in_num);// set the bit 1
            }

        } while (i < 10);
        for (int u = 0; u < 10; u++)
        {
            cout << endl << Numbers[u];
        }
        return 0;
    }
```